# About polluting the peer table

Tags: network, p2p

Is there a well-known method to pollute a specific user's peer table?

Eclipse attack is not available anymore due to the patch after a paper was introduced.

Can you give some keywords?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking for. Are you asking for terms denominating other network-level attacks?

Comment: YES! do you know an efficient way to pollute the victim's peer table with adversary's fake peers?